# Blender Symmetrize turning in wrong direction?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, pose-mode

I'm having an issue that I can't seem to figure out. Basically, when I symmetrize my model the bones are created on the opposite side as intended. However, they seem to be rotating in the wrong direction. I'm at a complete loss as to how to fix it, any help would be awesome.

Correct:
[image]

Incorrect:
[image]

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? (remove the useless objects) https://blend-exchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple. You've probably rotated the armature in object mode. The symmetrize function uses a bone's local `x-axis` so any rotation in object mode to the armature can cause the local `x-axis` to become unaligned with the `global orientation`.

Just press  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>A</kbd>  and choose `rotation` in object mode to ***apply rotations*** to the armature **before** symmetrizing the armature.

Apologies if this still doesn't work. It would help if you add the blend file to your question. You can use [Blend Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/)